# trigger sql server, two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi guys i want ask u if there is a way to create a trigger that update a table when another one recive a new row . 
thanks !

Comment: Yup.  It's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely it's possible.

```
create trigger tblTriggerAuditRecord on tblOrders
after update, insert
as
begin
  insert into tblOrdersAudit 
  (OrderID, OrderApprovalDateTime, OrderStatus, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn )
  select i.OrderID, i.OrderApprovalDateTime, i.OrderStatus, SUSER_SNAME(), getdate() 
  from  tblOrders t 
  inner join inserted i on t.OrderID=i.OrderID 
end
go
```

Source: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4055/create-a-simple-sql-server-trigger-to-build-an-audit-trail/

Reference material:[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) / [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables)

As a side note, *please do your research* before posting a question here, this is a fairly basic question that could be answered with a quick Google search.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Modify_Table_Trg
ON TableA
   AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE t
    SET    ColumnA = i.SomeColumn
    FROM   TableA t
           INNER JOIN INSERTED i
                ON  t.PrimaryKeyColumn = i.PrimaryKeyColumn
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a after insert trigger for the table in which you are inserting and Use 'Inserted' table , you can update the second table

---

```
create trigger UDT_Tab1Trigger on Tab1
after insert
as
begin
  update Tab2
  set col21=INSERTED.col11,
     col22 = INSERTED.col12
 FROM INSERTED
 WHERE Tab2.Id= INSERTED.Id 
end
go
```